# Selecting either one or ALL the values in a parameter in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a reporting project in SSRS. I have a parameter called '**customer**'. The values for this parameter are now populated with the sql query. I want to restrict this parameter such that the user should be able to select either **one customer** or **all the customers**. There should not be any possibilities to select either 2 or 3 customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an option in your parameter list called `All Customers` that is ordered so it sits at the top of the parameter list.

If you are manually adding parameter options, this ordering is easy.  If it is data-driven you can do a `union all` in your parameter value dataset to get the correct order:

```
select <Unique value that matches your customer ID type> as Value
      ,'All Customers' as Label
      ,1 as SortOrder

union all

select CustomerID as Value
      ,CustomerName as Label
      ,2 as SortOrder
from CustomerTable
order by SortOrder
        ,Label
```

and then in your query you just need to add the logic that handles this new `All` value:

```
select Columns
from Tables
where CustomerID = @Customer
   or @Customer = <Unique value that matches your customer ID type>
```